# How to do the monitoring upload status?

Tags: android, android-studio, upload, monitoring

Well i haven't been able to solve this, and i really need to get the upload status, when you upload someting using the MultipartUploadRequest, i want to print with a toast or anything else the status that appears on the notification bar. 
i've been following these tutorial but i haven't succeed:https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki/Monitoring-upload-status

i REALLY appreciate someone to tell why im not able to achieve this please. 
here's my code:

```
 public class CargarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        ////////////////-------------
        String correo = campo_correo.getText().toString().trim();
        String nombre = campo_nombre.getText().toString().trim();
        String apellido= campo_apellido.getText().toString().trim();
        String telefono= campo_telefono.getText().toString().trim();
        String categoria= customspinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String titulo = campo_titulo.getText().toString().trim();
        String descripcion = campo_descripcion.getText().toString().trim();
        String latitud = Double.toString(latitudeeeee);
        String longitud = Double.toString(longitudeeee);

        String s = (campo_publico.isChecked() ? "1" : "0");
        String r = (campo_terminos.isChecked() ? "1" : "0");

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name",correo) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .addParameter("nombre",nombre)
                    .addParameter("apellido",apellido)
                    .addParameter("telefono", telefono)
                    .addParameter("categoria", categoria)
                    .addParameter("titulo", titulo)
                    .addParameter("descripcion", descripcion)
                    .addParameter("publico", s)
                    .addParameter("terminos", r)
                    .addParameter("latitud",latitud)
                    .addParameter("longitud",longitud)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the link that you have provided, use the setDelegate method to get the upload status. The request will be like below

```
            new MultipartUploadRequest(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", correo) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .addParameter("nombre", nombre)
                    .addParameter("apellido", apellido)
                    .addParameter("telefono", telefono)
                    .addParameter("categoria", categoria)
                    .addParameter("titulo", titulo)
                    .addParameter("descripcion", descripcion)
                    .addParameter("publico", s)
                    .addParameter("terminos", r)
                    .addParameter("latitud", latitud)
                    .addParameter("longitud", longitud)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .setDelegate(new UploadStatusDelegate() {  //Add these lines to get upload status
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
                            // your code here
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse,
                                            Exception exception) {
                            // your code here
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Your success message here" + exception, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
                            // your code here
                        }
                    }).startUpload();
```

After file uploading, any one of the above methods will be invoked. print your messages over there

Answer (score 0):

best way for debug use Stetho facebook

[link](https://code.facebook.com/posts/393927910787513/stetho-a-new-debugging-platform-for-android/)